# random.forest.importance and XTS package

Tags: r

I am quite new to R coding, the TTR/XTS package and random.forest.importance functions.

I am extracting trading data using the xts function, calculating whether the difference between Close and Open is positive/negative/flat, applying a handful of technical indicators using the TTR function , and then combining the indicators to calculate the random.forest.importance function.

When I run the code, I get the

> Error in model.frame.default(formula, data, na.action = NULL) : variable lengths differ (found for 'Close').

Data:

```
Date Time Open    High     Low   Close TVolume
2017-10-12 14:00:00 1.18462 1.18487 1.18334 1.18347    1165
2017-10-12 15:00:00 1.18351 1.18377 1.18295 1.18347     884
2017-10-12 16:00:00 1.18348 1.18348 1.18265 1.18276    1000
2017-10-12 17:00:00 1.18245 1.18329 1.18242 1.18303    1184
2017-10-12 18:00:00 1.18305 1.18373 1.18284 1.18343     469
2017-10-12 19:00:00 1.18343 1.18343 1.18247 1.18303     886
```

Code as follows:

```
pkgs <- c('class', 'gmodels', 'quantmod', 'TTR','xts','corrplot','caret','FSelector')
    z <- head(tail(hist_r, samples+retro), samples)
    z <- as.xts(z[,2:6], order.by=as.POSIXct(z$Timestamp, origin='1970-01-01 00:00', tz='UTC'))
hist <- getHist(z)
h <- as.xts(hist)

price <- z$Close-z$Open
class = ifelse(price > 0,""'UP'"",ifelse(price <0,""'DOWN'"",'""FLAT'""))

    forceindex <- (z$Close-z$Open) * z$TVolume
    WillR5 <- WPR(z[,c(""'High'"",""'Low'"",""'Close'"")], n = 5)
    dataset = data.frame(class,forceindex,WillR5)
    dataset = na.omit(dataset)
dput(head(dataset, 10))

set.seed(5)
weights <- random.forest.importance(class~., dataset, importance.type = 1)
print(weights)
```

When I run dput, i get the following:

```
 tructure(list(Close = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("DOWN", "FLAT", "UP"), class = "factor"), Close.1 = c(-12.9382400000007, 0.107400000000227, -1.66915000000001, -0.290530000000006, -1.18667999999979, 0.0752800000000753, -0.244080000000094, 0.0653999999999928, -0.395999999999996, 0.372089999999928)
```

Would sincerely appreciate any help that anyone can give me

Many thanks in advance
Kkel

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at how to write a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3250126) example.

Comment: Thanks Loki....am struggling to follow as I am not not learnt coding at all. I took a look at the reproducible example page - any tips on what else I can provide to augment the above?

Comment: you should give an example of your data. You can use `dput(head(your_data, 10))` for example

Comment: Hi Loki, appreciate the direction, does this help? (sorry if I have misunderstood): tructure(list(Close = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("DOWN", "FLAT", "UP"), class = "factor"),  Close.1 = c(-12.9382400000007, 0.107400000000227, -1.66915000000001,  -0.290530000000006, -1.18667999999979, 0.0752800000000753, -0.244080000000094, 0.0653999999999928, -0.395999999999996,  0.372089999999928)

Comment: you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47749429/edit) that to your question. also show the original `dput()` command, so that we can identify which object it is. Also try to run the code in a clean R session, so that you can find out if we can also reproduce everything with the code given.

Comment: also please add the libraries you are using at the top of your code

Comment: tried again Loki - thanks again for being patient with my amateurish attempts

Comment: Hi Loki - any chance that the above information was helpful?

Comment: No not yet. We cannot see what the original dput was and furthermore there are typos in the S(!) tructure. Please make sure it is completely reproducible for other users. Only thus we are able to help you. Otherwise you risk your question being closed as "not reproducible".